# How to display related posts by same publish date?

Tags: query

I need a query to show posts with same "publish date" as related posts.
For Ex. if the post is published in 2012-08-02, i want to show other posts which are published in 2012-08-02 in bottom of the post.
Is there any solution?
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Get the date of current post:

```
$date = get_the_date('Y-m-d');
```

Get year, month and day from the $date variable.

```
$exploded = explode('-', $date);
$year = $exploded[0];
$month = $exploded[1];
$day = $exploded[2];
```

Lastly, query the posts that has the same publish date.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year'  => $year,
            'month' => $month,
            'day'   => $day,
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Add any query arguments and display the query results as you wish.